# Rails activerecord-reputation-system scope / query issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope

I'm implementing the [activerecord-reputation-system gem](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system) and having an issue scoping the most 'loved' articles.

```
/articles_controller
def index
  ....
  @loved_articles = Article.page(params[:page]).find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, {:order => 'votes DESC, created_at DESC'})
  ....
end
```

I tried calling .per(5) after [:page]).per(5).... but rails gave me an "undefined method `per'" error

```
/article model

def self.loved
  find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, {:order => 'votes DESC'}).first(5)
end
```

-

I would imagine calling .first(5) would scope it, but nothing is happening - in my views, the loop is just chewing through all my articles. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind - I'm not using pagination...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - I'm not using pagination...

Added `@loved_articles = Article.loved` in my controller

Answer (score 1):

How about write like this

`Article.find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, {:order => 'votes DESC, created_at DESC'}).per(5)`